# View with list of all taxonomy terms except active node's term

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I have an request to create a view based on taxonomy terms. Basically it's opposite of standard Taxonomy Terms list.

I have an content type for videos. Each video has its category of course. On full node (and on taxonomy pages) first view lists all related nodes of that category (taxonomy term), format used is flexslider and contextual filters are the same as the generic taxonomy view has (taxonomy terms with depth). It works fine.

Now I need a list of all other nodes from other categories, grouped by taxonomy term. And it's not so hard until I want to EXCLUDE the category (term) of a current node. Logically because it is already there.

If there is no solution please advise me how to sort groups in that way the active category comes first on the list. i.e. NODE1 has TERM1, on its node first is a list of all nodes from TERM1 and then comes TERM2, below TERM3, etc.